# Trying to connect to a remote server using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have an Ubuntu server running Tomcat, and I want to connect my Eclipse EE to it so I can work with JSP.

I have no problem connecting to a similar Tomcat service when it's installed on my machine (not a server), but whenever I try to connect to the remote server I don't seem to have the option of choosing a Tomcat service.

Is there some guide you can recommend (I didn't find one), or is there something I did wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The "remote" Tomcat (or more generally the app server) must be configured to permit such connection.

Did you start the remote server with these parameters:

`-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n`

Alternatively you can add the word `jpda` at the end of the `startup.sh` (or .bat) script just when calling the `catalina.sh` script.

Everything is documented on the [Apache Tomcat Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing).

After enabling those options, you have also another task to do: enabling the network connection to the configured port (8000 in the above options). It depends which firewall is installed on the server but usually it is `iptables`.

Example of `iptables` command to enable connection to port 8000:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT
```

If your server have a GUI installed, one easiest way is to use the "ufw" – short for 'uncomplicated firewall' as explained in [this site](https://www.howtogeek.com/115116/how-to-configure-ubuntus-built-in-firewall/) which is just a graphical way to configure the `iptables`.

One way to test the connectivity to the server (if the port is open) is to use telnet from your computer like this:

```
telnet your.distant.host 8000
```

and if the command opens, the port is accessible, if the telnet command times out, the port is closed.